# How to print useful debug info on an X509Chain?

Tags: c#, x509certificate

The `X509Certificate` class has a `ToString()` method that pretty-prints all of the useful details... the `X509Chain` class does not.

I'm running into the fairly generic `SslPolicyErrors`: `RemoteCertificateChainErrors`. But, I don't know what to print from the chain that would be helpful in debugging.

The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509chain?view=netcore-3.1#examples) shows a lot of element traversal and printing. But, I'm confused... should I print the ChainStatus of each ChainElement, like they show, or the top-level ChainStatus?

I suspect I'll wrap this up in an extension method... What information do I need to print to be able to debug `RemoteCertificateChainErrors`?

Comment: It depends on what is useful for you, your debugging strategies and the depth of debugging information. I think, the question in its way is offtopic.

Comment: It is really scenario dependent. For a diagnostics tool like SSLDiag, each chain status must be printed, https://github.com/jexuswebserver/JexusManager/blob/v13.0.0.23/JexusManager/Features/Main/SslDiagDialog.cs#L326

Comment: I'm sorry if you find my action aggressive. From my point of view, the question is not properly formulated, because there is no specific information on what kind of debugging information you want to see. What goal you want to pursue, how verbose this information should be, I would expect to see all this in your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What exactly is wrong is kind of up to interpretation (one of the certificates in the chain might be invalid or your host may not trust one of the certificates), but you won't get far without the certificate and status from every element.

Here's a few extension methods that I whipped up to pretty-print useful debugging info from the chain object.

```cs
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Security.Cryptography;
    using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
    using System.Text;

    public static class X509Extensions
    {
        public static string ToDisplayString(this X509Chain chain)
        {
            var b = new StringBuilder();

            b.AppendLine($"[{nameof(chain.ChainPolicy.RevocationFlag)}]");
            b.AppendLine($"  {chain.ChainPolicy.RevocationFlag}");
            b.AppendLine();
            b.AppendLine($"[{nameof(chain.ChainPolicy.RevocationMode)}]");
            b.AppendLine($"  {chain.ChainPolicy.RevocationMode}");
            b.AppendLine();
            b.AppendLine($"[{nameof(chain.ChainPolicy.VerificationFlags)}]");
            b.AppendLine($"  {chain.ChainPolicy.VerificationFlags}");
            b.AppendLine();
            b.AppendLine($"[{nameof(chain.ChainPolicy.VerificationTime)}]");
            b.AppendLine($"  {chain.ChainPolicy.VerificationTime}");
            b.AppendLine();
            b.AppendLine($"[Application Policy]");
            foreach (var policy in chain.ChainPolicy.ApplicationPolicy)
            {
                b.AppendLine($"  {policy.ToDisplayString()}");
            }
            b.AppendLine();
            b.AppendLine($"[Certificate Policy]");
            foreach (var policy in chain.ChainPolicy.CertificatePolicy)
            {
                b.AppendLine($"  {policy.ToDisplayString()}");
            }
            b.AppendLine();
            b.AppendLine($"[Elements]");
            foreach (var (element, index) in chain.ChainElements.Cast<X509ChainElement>().Select((element, index) => (element, index)))
            {
                b.AppendLine();
                b.AppendLine($"[Element {index + 1}]");
                b.AppendLine();
                b.Append(element.Certificate.ToString());
                b.AppendLine();
                b.AppendLine($"[Status]");
                foreach (var status in element.ChainElementStatus)
                {
                    b.AppendLine($"  {status.ToDisplayString()}");
                }
            }

            return b.ToString();
        }

        public static string ToDisplayString(this Oid oid)
        {
            return oid.FriendlyName == oid.Value
                ? $"{oid.Value}"
                : $"{oid.FriendlyName}: {oid.Value}";
        }

        public static string ToDisplayString(this X509ChainStatus status)
        {
            return $"{status.Status}: {status.StatusInformation}";
        }
    }
```

And you can call this from any remote certificate validation callback.

```cs
bool CertificateValidationCallback(
    object sender,
    X509Certificate certificate,
    X509Chain chain,
    SslPolicyErrors errors)
{
    if (errors == SslPolicyErrors.None)
    {
        return true;
    }

    logger.LogError($"SSL Policy Error(s): {1}", errors);
    logger.LogError($"X509 Certificate:{0}{1}", Environment.NewLine, certificate.ToString());
    logger.LogError($"X509 Chain:{0}{1}", Environment.NewLine, chain.ToDisplayString());

    return false;
}
```

Comment: The information printed using this extension method gave me enough information to find that I was missing a specific certificate in this chain in my certificate store.